# Where is the web server root directory on Angstrom Linux (BeagleBoard | BeagleBone)?

Tags: webserver, port, beagleboard, angstrom-linux

I'm trying to find the default web server directory on my BeagleBone with Angstrom Linux. That is, where are the files served when I go to:

```
http://beaglebone.local:80
```

Another way would be to answer this question: How do I find out what directory a port number points to on my BeagleBone with Angstrom Linux?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The BeagleBone|BeagleBoard Angstrom Linux distribution ships with a socket server that runs as a service using node.js and bonescript in:

```
/var/lib/cloud9/bonescript/
```

and can be accessed at: http://beaglebone.local:80

You can also install [lighttpd](http://www.lighttpd.net/) with

```
opkg install lighttpd
```

and will install a config file into

```
/etc/lighttpd.conf
```

which can be altered to set the default web directory wherever you like.

Comment: Do you know how I can disable the standard cloud9/bonescript node, and set my own web server to launch as the default upon startup?  (I'm using a twistd server). Thanks!

Comment: Not off hand. You might try to post your question.

Answer (score 1):

I found the following worked, evenutally:

```
systemctl disable bonescript.service
systemctl disable bonescript-autorun.service
systemctl disable cloud9.service
systemctl disable bonescript.socket
```

Use 'systemctl list-units' to check they've stopped. Possibly, there's a correct order you have to do these in, I had to fiddle around and repeat these a bit before they were all dead. You could probably just nuke the symlinks in /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants and reboot.